# How to increase memory usage in MySQL Server to improve speed?

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, iis-7

I have a Windows 2008 server with 8GB of RAM running IIS7 and MySQL. I've been tracking the memory, cpu and disk usage on the server and I found out that MySQL is using only 250MB of RAM, keeping the disks very busy, even though I have plenty of free ram laying around.

In SQL Server I can easily set the amount of memory I want it to use, I am looking for the same setting in MySQL.

How can I configure MySQL to use more memory and reduce the cpu and disk usage?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`table_cache` is the most useful configuration directive to change. Each time MySQL accesses a table, it loads the table into cache. If you've got a high number of tables, it's faster to have them cached.

Take a look at your server variables by running:

```
show status;
```

and have a look for the variable `open_tables`. If this is the same as your `table_cache` value, and `opened_tables` keeps going up, then you need to increase the `table_cache` value in your configuration file. You'll find a balance by experimenting with these variables during peak times. You want to configure it so that at peak times, there are a low amount of `opened_tables` even after the server has been up for a long time.

`key_buffer_size` is also a good variable to experiment with. This variable affects the index buffer size, and making this variable bigger increases MySQL's index handling speed. You can look at the variables with the `show variables;` command again, and compare `key_read_requests` to `key_reads`. Ideally, you want the ratio between these two variables to be as low as possible, and you can do this by increasing the size of the `key_buffer_size`. If you set this variable higher, you will have less writes and reads directly to and from the disk, which was your main concern.

Comment: Actually the command is `show status;` [to see status variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html) such as `Open_tables` and `Opened_tables`.  `table_cache` appears to have been removed in recent MySQL versions.

Answer (score 7):

You need to change values in the `my.cnf` file and restart MySQL, although you can change many of them whilst MySQL is running, too ('SET GLOBAL VARIABLE=*value*').

You will probably want to look at increasing `key_buffer_size`, `sort_buffer`, `read_buffer` and `table_cache` for starters and probably `innodb_buffer_pool_size` ,if you have any InnoDB tables. Some of these values you can increase a long way (even two orders of magnitude) especially given your hardware. MySQL's defaults are extremely conservative and seemed to be aimed at common mixed-use desktops of about ten years ago. Oh, and be warned that the 32-bit version will have trouble using more than 2GB of RAM.

Look in [the MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html) for more information and guidance.